# Multiple KafkaConsumer on multiple Kafka Cluster in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

Want to create `homogeneous kafka consumers` on different clusters from a Spring boot application using `spring-kafka`.

i.e Want to create a Kafka Consumer object for class defined already which listens to multiple cluster defined dynamically.

> e.g:  Lets say a Spring boot application S which contains the
>   `template for kafkaconsumer`. And there are three Kafka Clusters
>   custer1, cluster2, cluster3. The application S act as an aggregator of
>   data produced from each of the cluster. Here the solution would be
>   three `consumers` of the same template will be listening on individual
>   cluster in `parallel`.

Is the above scenario is possible using spring-kafka?

Answer (score 3):

A `@KafkaListener` can't talk to multiple clusters. You would need to delegate to the real listener...

```
@KafkaListener(..., containerFactory="cluster1Factory")
public void listen1(...) {
    this.delegate.listen(...);
}

@KafkaListener(..., containerFactory="cluster2Factory")
public void listen2(...) {
    this.delegate.listen(...);
}

etc.
```

Comment: The problem is cannot have multiple factory in the code, need to have a single class which could be deployed dynamically as needed. We cannot add n listeners and n factory as the n is determined at runtime only.

Comment: `@KafkaListener` is not designed to be added dynamically at runtime to a running application; it can, however, be achieved by dynamically creating a child application context for each `@KafkaListener`.